# Let $\pi : \tilde S \rightarrow S$ be an étale cover of degree 2. Then for any divisor $D$ of $S$ we have $\pi_*\pi^*D = 2D$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\pi : \tilde S \rightarrow S$ be an étale cover of degree 2 of complex algebraic surfaces. Then for any divisor $D$ of $S$ we have $\pi_*\pi^*D = 2D$. Intuitively I see how this would be true. But how does one prove it?

Comment: Idea: reduce to effective case. Then, we want to show that $\pi_\ast\pi^\ast D-2D$ is zero. It should suffice to check that it paired against a sufficiently general ample divisor is zero. Find such an ample divisor intersecting the curves of $D$ transversely (or just reduce to the case of a prime divisor). Then, this should reduce the question to the same question on curves. This case is trivial. Indeed, there since $\pi$ is étale $\pi^\ast q=p+p'$ for some $p,p'$ and so $\pi_\ast \pi^\ast p=\pi(p)+\pi(p')=2q$. This is just an idea though, I haven't totally fleshed it out.

Comment: @AlexYoucis thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hartshorne tells you how to define $\pi_*: \mathrm{Pic}\, X\to\mathrm{Pic}\,Y$ where $\pi:X\to Y$ is a finite map of degree $d$ of smooth varieties (flatness is enough). If $L$ is a line bundle on $X$, then $\pi_*L=\Lambda^d \pi_*L\otimes \Lambda^d(\pi_*\mathcal{O}_X)^{-1}$, where the right hand side $\pi_*$ is as sheaves.

In your case, $\pi_*\mathcal{O}_X=\mathcal{O}_Y\oplus M$, $M$ a line bundle. If $G=\mathcal{O}_Y(D)$, using the above defintion, it is clear that $\pi_*\pi^* G=\mathcal{O}_Y(2D)$, since as sheaves, $\pi_*\pi^*(G)=G\oplus G\otimes M$.

Comment: This is by decomposing the $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$-representation on the sheaf (the pushforward)? Is that where the decomposition is coming from?

Comment: Yes. You can also see it as follows. Since you have a natural inclusion $\mathcal{O}_Y\to\pi_*\mathcal{O}_X$, with cokernel $M$ and this splits by trace map in characteristic zero ($\neq 2$).